# Ошибка при исполнении ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть ajax запрос, передаю данные, на сервер они приходят, обрабатываются - все ок. Но не всегда они приходят обратно. Появляется ошибка:

> Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText:
>   "error"}

Мое приложение обрабатывает клики по ячейкам таблицы, куда пользователь вводит число. По нажатию "save" идет отправка данных на сервер. Таких кликов по ячейкам может быть много, в среднем 6-7 из них отправляются-принимаются успешно, 8-й уже не возвращается пользователю. В чем может быть проблема и как это можно решить? Заранее спасибо!
Ajax у меня следующий:

```
$.ajax({url: '@Url.Action("AddHours", "Diary")',
            type: "Post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { employeeId: emplId, hours: hours},
            success: function (data) {
                $('#t').find(".dtHour").html(data.DayHours);
                $('#emplId').html(data.TotalHours);                    
            },
            error:function(num) {
                alert(num);
                }});
```

Вариант добавления такой строчки уже пробовала, не помогло:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Решение: вроде помог ответ с событием от клика по кнопке https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313283/jquery-ajax-jqxhr-status-is-always-0 Во всяком случае глюков пока нет. Как оказалось, важный момент: у меня была обработка отправки запроса серверу по нажатию клавиши enter. Там тоже нужно вставить строчку return false;

Comment: Нужно больше информации

Comment: какой именно информации? Могу добавить, что сбой происходит еще во время того (или перед тем) как сервер отрабатывает свою часть (успешно). Сервер отправляет данные, но они уже не принимаются. (в браузере под дебагом error: num = Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"})

Comment: Может быть забивается память, т.к. много данных обрабатывается. Или т.к. много запросов, они теряются в какой-то момент?...

Comment: А каковы значения еще двух параметров error коллбэк функции? Вам нужно анализировать эти параметры чтобы обнаружить такие ошибки как network error, timeout, abort... См [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8534704/315935), [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9964979/315935), [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3617710/315935) и др.

Comment: Браузер в консоли по идее должен написать собственную ошибку, что-то вроде домен не тот, ошибка доступа, показать ответ нельзя, бла-бла

Comment: Вот все параметры ошибки: jqXHR = Object {readyState: 0, responseText: "", status: 0, statusText: "error"}, textStatus = "error", errorThrown = ""

Comment: @Daria: я бы рекоменровал проанализировать проблему более детально. Для начала, нужно выяснить с какай стороны неполадки: со стороны клиента или сервера. Нужно сделать HTTP trace. Например, можно использовать [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) или Developer Tools IE/Chrome/Firefox (старт нажав F12 и выбрать Network). Прежде всего, нужно выяснить посылается ли запрос, дающий ошибку, или нет.

Comment: @Oleg: Chrome->Network->Status Text: "(canceled)" вместо "202 OK" и во вкладке Response этой строки: Failed to load response data. Сам запрос на сервер прошел (это видно как минимум в VS под дебагом).

Comment: @Daria: Лучше было бы постепенно добавлять к тексту вопроса дополнительную информацию. Например, неплохо было бы взглянуть на "неправильный бутерброд" - ответ с сервера, который не может загрузится. Где точно присутствует строка Failed to load response data? Если в body, то ответ не соответствует запросу, и тогда ошибку нужно искать на стороне сервера.

Comment: @Oleg: строка Failed to load response data просто в окне Response. Вроде помог  ответ с событием от клика по кнопке http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313283/jquery-ajax-jqxhr-status-is-always-0 . Во всяком случае глюков пока нет...

Comment: @Daria: о какой кнопке идет речь? В вопросе Вы писали про "клики по ячейкам таблицы". Какое изменение Вы сделали?

Comment: @Oleg: Запрос серверу отправлялся по клику на кнопке (либо нажатием клавиши enter). Возможно из-за того, что кликов было много, возникала ошибка, т.е. нужно было после каждого клика событию onclick возвращать false (return false; в методе-обработчике клика по кнопке). Почему при этом происходила ошибка Ajax - не знаю. Но все равно большое спасибо за помощь!!

Comment: @Daria: пожалуйста!